# RxSwift - auto reloading UITableView initialized with Observable

Tags: ios, uitableview, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I have main `UITableView` with some Todos that are populated used an array of Observables:

```
// on viewDidLoad
self.todosViewModel.todos.asObservable()
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "TodoViewCell", cellType: TodoTableViewCell.self)) { (row, todo, cell) in
        cell.status.image = todo.getStatusImage()
        cell.title.text = todo.title.value
        cell.todoDescription.text = todo.description.value
        cell.dueDate.text = String(describing: Utilities.dateFormatter.string(from: todo.dueDate.value))
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

On another screen I can add/edit the data and then, click "save" button to append a new todo or modify the one being edited. This works great, except that the `tableView` don't reload automatically, forcing me to call `tableView.reloadData()` on `viewDidAppear`, which is triggered when the other screen is dismissed.

So,

**Is there a native way for me to reload a table automatically when then `todosViewModel` variable is updated**?

**EDIT:**

If on the screen of edition of the todo I reassociate the `todosViewModel`'s `value` property with the same value, it also works:

```
self.todosViewModel.todos.value = self.todosViewModel.todos.value
```

That's pretty ugly, but I only know how to reload a tableView using one of those ways.

Comment: Are you sure `todos` emit any events when you save or edit an item?

Comment: Not directly. When I `append` a new `todo` or reassociate a new value to the base `todos` it works. When I edit, no. I don't know how I should send an event to the model who fills the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

> When I append a new todo or reassociate a new value to the base todos it works. When I edit, no.

That's the whole point. For the `UITableView` to update, your `todos` have to emit when an item inside has been edited or you have to bind something from your `todo` within the cell (this way you cannot change hight of the cell but you can push some dynamic information onto the cell).

Another option would be to map some observable from `todo` to the index of the cell where it's presented and call `UITableView.reloadRows` to update your edited cell.

I would recommend you to take a look at [RxDataSources examples](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/tree/master/Example).

Comment: If as I'm doing there is no caveats or performance issues, I can stand with it. For my case, a RxDataSource is overkill, but I'm taking a look anyway.